# How to cast list collection to derived collection object?

Tags: c#, collections, casting, derived-class

I have created a derived collection object to introduce some added functionality to filter the active records in the collection as shown in the below code snippet. How to achieve it as i want to just filter the same collection while keeping the original references in the filter without creating copy.

```
public class ExtendedTypes : List<ExtendedType>
{
    public ExtendedTypes Active
    {
        get { return this.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList(); } // Compile Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Filtering an existing list**

You mentioned that you wanted to just filter the existing list without keeping a copy. In this case, creating a `List` won't do, since creating a list from the subset will always create a new collection, not just a filter. `List<T>` is not a lazily-evaluated collection.

What you probably need to do is either define `Active` as `IEnumerable<ExtendedType>` and return the result of the `Where` directly (using LINQ's lazy implementation), or, if you're in WPF, use something like `CollectionView` as an [additional filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348(v=vs.110).aspx) on top of a collection, like this:

```
public ICollectionView ActiveTypes 
{
    get
    {
        if (_activeTypes == null)
        {
            _activeTypes = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myExtendedTypes);
            _activeTypes.Filter = (type) => (type as ExtendedType).IsActive;
        }
        return _activeTypes;
    }
}
```

You can now bind to `ActiveTypes` and get only a subset of the original list, filtered by the result of the `Filter` clause.

**Creating a new List**

However, assuming `ExtendedType` is a Reference type, you don't have to worry about copies of the items themselves being made by duplicating the list. If you don't mind creating a copy of the *list* with the same references, use my original answer:

The compiler is correct, in the sense that an `ExtendedTypes` is-a `List<ExtendedType>`, but not the other way around, and `ToList()` create a `List<ExtendedType>`.

There is, however, a simple workaround. Rather than `ToList`, just create a new `ExtendedTypes` with a constructor that initializes from a collection:

```
public class ExtendedTypes : List<ExtendedType>
{
    public ExtendedTypes (IEnumerable<ExtendedType> items) : base(items)
    {}

    public ExtendedTypes Active
    {
        get { return new ExtendedTypes(this.Where(x => x.IsActive)); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is close to my requirement. I am using WPF, so as you mentioned about CollectionView, can you provide an example of using it as per my requirement.